# How to create a bulk edit form in react-admin

Tags: react-admin

I have a list of transactions in react-admin.
These transactions have a category and I want to update many transactions at the same time.

The list should show a textfield where I can add the category. And a submit button at the bottom of the list.

Is there a easy way to create this bulk edit form? Or do I need to create this from scatch.

I found the updateMany method in the dataprovider en the examples but none of these show input fields in a list.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please see [ask].

Comment: Look at here: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/AdvancedTutorials.html#creating-and-editing-a-record-from-the-list-page